# How to remove text between two specified strings using Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have following lines of data

```
File created by
Status 23:
Status 24:
Status 25:
Status 26:
Address
Address 112: 044 0891.
Address 113: 044 1502.
Message log (200 messages)
Message 1:
Message 2:
Message 3:
```

I wish to delete text between line 1("File created by" ) and line “Message log (200 messages)”.

Can someone please provide some suggestions and thoughts on this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is your expected content?

Comment: I just want to keep last three rows. Thanks

Comment: Search "Message log", press ENTER, go to the next line, press SHIFT+CTRL+HOME and DELETE, and record a macro for this.

Comment: Not sure if i understood your problem but you can simply select those lines in notepadd ++ and press delete button.

Comment: But I have 200+ files with same data and I want to do it once for all.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following find and replace in regex mode, with DOT ALL mode enabled:

**Find:**

```
(?<=File created by).*(?=Message log \(200 messages\))
```

**Replace:**

```
(nothing)
```

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `.*Message log \(200 messages\)\R`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
.*                              : 0 or more any character
Message log \(200 messages\)    : literally
\R                              : any kind of line break
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Message 1:
Message 2:
Message 3:
```

Repeat the same for all files.

---

If all your files are in the same directory, you can do this replacement in the tab "Find in files"